# Cross Domain SignalR with WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, signalr

Question on SignalR cross domain. I have the following layers in my .NET application:

- Data
- DAL
- Service (using WCF)
- ClientWeb1 (cw1)
- ClientWeb2 (cw2)

The reason for the Service layer is to act as a middle man between the SignalR hubs on cw1 / cw2.

The goal being cw1 will send some kind of update message to its controller, this then updates cw1's hub which then broadcasts it to all cw1's (standard signalr functionality).

What I need also is for cw1's controller to send an additional message to my service layer so that cw2 clients also learn of the update from cw1. At this point I want my service layer to be able to call cw2's hub and fire a message to all cw2's clients based off of cw1's initial message.

So my question is this: How do I gain access to either cw1's or cw2's hubs from an external service layer? Is this possible? I believe it is but cannot seem to find a best answer due to numerous deprecated SignalR functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for your answers. I got around this in the end by carrying out the following steps:

Getting rid of the WCF service.

Setting up another web project on a virtual directory, this would be where I keep my Hub(s).

I then pointed my SignalR clients from the other 2 web projects to this by changing the client side script refs, e.g.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/MyThirdVirtualDirWebProj/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I can then send messages to/from my third 'middle man' project's hub. There is possibly a better way to do this, maybe with XSockets as mentioned above but this seems to work fairly nicely.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge this is *not* possible. To be able to communicate with the Hub you either need to send it messages through its public API **OR** you need to have another private API (in your case the WCF service) that sits next to hub in the same ASP.NET instance which can broadcast messages itself using `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>()` or, an for a cleaner separation of concerns, using some shared internal interface which decouples the WCF service from the "SignalRness" altogether.

I would suggest using the latter approach of a separate service since, aside from just being a better separation of concerns, sending messages through the public API means that anyone who is connected to the Hub could send the same messages if they figured out what they were. Either that or you would need to introduce/use a different level of security checks for those specific hub methods to ensure that only certain callers have the rights to invoke them.

Answer (score 1):

dont know howto do it with SignalR, but it´s easy with XSockets.NET.

https://github.com/codeplanner/XSocketsWCF/blob/master/src/XSocketsWCF/XSocketsWCF/WCF/Service/RoomService.cs

The link is to the WCF connected to the websocket server, but you can download the project... It´s all there.

Another (of several) advantage is that XSockets will provide clustered servers form 3.0 so that a message on server 1 will arrive on server2 (and vice versa), then you will not need the WCF part.

About the 3.0 release: http://xsockets.net/blog/sneak-peek-at-the-30-features

Regards
Uffe